# Raspbgerry pi 4 HDMI works on TV but not on monitor

Tags: hdmi, pi-4

My pi 4 outputs as normal to my TV but when connected to an HP2311 monitor there is no display.

I have tried the usual config.txt tricks i.e.

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

hdmi_drive=2

hdmi_safe=1

config_hdmi_boost=4
```

in various configurations of commented, uncommented. But the only thing that works is if my PC is simultaneously driving the monitor through either the DVI or VGA input. In which case I can then turn the PC off and continue with the pi until next boot.
The monitor works fine with Pi B, 2b and 3b. But with a different HDMI cable. I've ordered a mini to standard HDMI adapter to try the same 'good' cable.

Comment: Is your monitor plugged into hdmi 0 (next to power connector)? What resolution is your monitor?

Comment: Yes it is in the port next to the power conn. I've tried both forr most configurations

Comment: What resolution is your monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
- Verify that the monitor cable is connected to HDMI0 (closest to USB-C power)
- If resolution has been modified from defaults, reset to default
- If available on the monitor make sure the default input is set to HDMI.
I think modern HP LED monitors have that setting available.

Comment: Yes the monitor does have a default setting  whioch was already set as HDMI.

Comment: I changed it to DVI and then back. Neither made any difference. This is tedious as I have to power down the pc then test the change as I then don't get any video I have to power up the PC, which is on DVI to enable the pi then log on to the pi to answer the question.

Comment: The monitor is capable of 1920 x 1080, 1080p the earlier pi's have no problem with the monitor I think I'll wait until I can try a different cable.